# Refiner value lost when entering keyword search

Tags: search, search-results, refiner

I'm bringing the user to a search result page by passing a search refiner from the previous page. The refiner is showing checked as it should. Also the search results are refining as it should.

The issue is when I starts entering the keyword search, the refiner value is not being passed along with the query and the result is a search result based on the keywords only and the refiner comes back unchecked.

How can I retain that refiner value and search by using keywords simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to convert my API to description, tittle, and url

Comment: Is refiner and search Box is attached to same search results web part?

Comment: Yes.  Both refiner and search box point to a search result web part.

Comment: What version of SP are you using?

Comment: Currently SharePoint Online for testing, but I will need to port the solution to 2013.  Thanks.